# Open Hamburger Menu by Default on Page Load

Tags: javascript, jquery, hamburger-menu

Below is my code and it displays a closed hamburger menu or icon by default. How to open the hamburger menu by default on page load?

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var trigger = $('.hamburger'),
      overlay = $('.overlay'),
     isClosed = false;

    trigger.click(function () {
      hamburger_cross();      
    });

    function hamburger_cross() {    

      if (isClosed == true) {         
        overlay.hide();
        trigger.removeClass('is-open');
        trigger.addClass('is-closed');
        isClosed = false;
      } else {   
        overlay.show();
        trigger.removeClass('is-closed');
        trigger.addClass('is-open');
        isClosed = true;
      }
     }

    $('[data-toggle="offcanvas"]').click(function () {
        $('#wrapper').toggleClass('toggled');
    });  
    });
```

Comment: After `isClosed = false;` just put `hamburger_cross()`.

Answer (score 0):

You can run your function `hamburger_cross();` next after `$(document).ready(function () {` or for a more conventional way, after your variables declaration.